# Create an Entity (Beginner)

Tags: 7, entities

beginner here,

I am trying to follow the typical entity example and create my own entity in Drupal 7. So I basically changed the name from typical_entity_example_1 to source_entity and the test fails (see picture below). I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, any advice would be much appreciated.

install file:

```
function source_entity_schema() {
  $schema = array();
  $schema['source_entity'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for source_entity.',
    'fields' => array(
      'teid' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'Entity title.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'description' => array(
        'description' => 'Entity description.',
        'type' => 'text',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('teid'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

Module file:

```
<?php

function source_entity_info() {
  $info = array(
    'source_entity' => array(
      'label' => t('Source Entity 1'),
      'base table' => 'source_entity',
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'teid',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $info;
}
```

Test file

```
class SourceEntityUnitTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {
  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
      'name' => 'Source Entity Test 1',
      'description' => 'Check existence and possibilities of source_entity.',
      'group' => 'Source Entity',
    );
  }


  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp('source_entity');
  }

  public function testSourceEntity1() {
    $entity_description = entity_get_info('source_entity');
    $this->assertEqual($entity_description['base table'], 'source_entity', t("Entity type 'source_entity' exists."));

    $new_entity = entity_create('source_entity', array());
    $this->assertFalse($new_entity, t("Can't create an instance of source_entity because 'source_entity' entity type has not create callback."));
  }

}
```

[image: The test results]

Answer (score 0):

**Module file:**
Hook name is source_entity_info()  insted of source_entity_entity_info()

```
    <?php

    function source_entity_entity_info() {
      $info = array(
        'source_entity' => array(
          'label' => t('Source Entity 1'),
          'base table' => 'source_entity',
          'entity keys' => array(
            'id' => 'teid',
          ),
        ),
      );
      return $info;

}
```

[image]